# Rewrite old format with dynamic query string to new dynamic equivalent format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Actually I have a site but I don't know how exactly one can resolve this kind of issue.

So, my site is qapaper.com and there are some links which redirect on one single page with PHP GET methods which are:

```
 https://qapaper.com/first.php?id=1
 https://qapaper.com/first.php?id=2
 https://qapaper.com/first.php?id=3
 https://qapaper.com/first.php?id=4
```

Each having question papers of different year, now here comes the question that how can I change them to something like:

```
https://qapaper.com/first
https://qapaper.com/second 
https://qapaper.com/third
https://qapaper.com/fourth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only **four** entries, you could do it *statically*

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# condensated way to redirect /first.php?id=[1-4] to /first /second /third or /fourth
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}::first \s/first\.php\?id=1\s.+::(first)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}::second \s/first\.php\?id=2\s.+::(second)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}::third \s/first\.php\?id=3\s.+::(third)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}::fourth \s/first\.php\?id=4\s.+::(fourth)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite back
RewriteRule ^first$ /first.php?id=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^second$ /first.php?id=2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^third$ /first.php?id=3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fourth$ /first.php?id=4 [L,NC]
```

Otherwise, you could use `RewriteMap` (see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html))

Comment: can you also help me with any dynamic approach to this?

Comment: You can check the link I gave you to use a `RewriteMap`